# divide txt data into two sets according to text vocab distribution

Tags: distributions, sampling, natural-language

I want to split a list of sentences into two lists. But I want this such that the distribution of word frequencies be the same in both sets. How can I do this?

Comment: In general you cannot do it. This raises two questions you need to address to make your question answerable: (1) how should we quantitatively evaluate possible *approximate* solutions to determine which, if any, might be acceptable and which would be best among them?  (2) Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Let X be the original list. If I understand correctly, you want to split X into X1 and X2, which have the same word frequency distributions.

You can first get the word frequency distribution of X. Then, for each word in the frequency distribution, extract half the occurrences into another list. This should result in X1 and X2. There will be minor differences when the frequency count is not divisible by 2.

Comment: The question asks to split the "list of sentences."  That means individual sentences must stay together.